# expecting a ; , or )?

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm trying to build source files for a application in a weather server. nbsp2ldm

it uses includes from another programs code.

When I run make like instructed it tells me

`/awips2/ldm/include/pq.h:77:37: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘prod_par’
         const prod_par_t* restrict  prod_par,`

Heres the context:

```
typedef struct {
    prod_info info;
    void*     data;
    void*     encoded;
    size_t    size;
} prod_par_t;

typedef struct {
    timestampt inserted;
    off_t      offset;
    bool       is_oldest;
    bool       is_full;
    bool       is_locked;
} queue_par_t;

typedef void pq_next_func(
        const prod_par_t* restrict  prod_par,
        const queue_par_t* restrict queue_par,
        void* restrict              app_par);
```

Since this is code that is in the release version of a program I assume this should just work but it's not.

Am I missing a compiler or library?

Thanks

Comment: You might be better off contacting the program's authors for support.

Comment: `restrict` is not a C++ keyword; are you trying to compile C99/C11 code with `g++` or something? Beyond that, `typedef`s of a function with named parameters don't make sense (at the very least it's pointless).

Comment: I believe the typedef should look like this: `typedef void (*pq_next_func)(const ...)`

Comment: ^^^^ So i'm going to assume wrong compiler

Comment: @Kosta that would be a different type

Comment: You can probably avoid this with `#ifdef __cplusplus` `#define restrict`  although no doubt there will be other things such as `extern "C"` to chuck in as well

Comment: In C++ no need to do `typedef struct {} X;` You can simply fo `struct X {};`